# Java MySQL & Java Confusion

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to make a authentication system in Java, but I have no idea if this will work. Logically to me, this code will only pull the first row (id = 1) and not anything after that?

```
public boolean authUser(String user, String pass) throws Exception
{
    boolean authenticated = false;
    int id = 0;
    String username = "", password = "";

    Connection authConn = getConnection();

    Statement stat = authConn.createStatement();
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);

    if(rs.next())
    {
        id = rs.getInt("id");
        username = rs.getString("user");
        password = rs.getString("pass");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error 20-01: Empty Table");
    }

    authConn.close();

    if(username.equals(user))
    {
        if(password.equals(pass))
        authenticated = true;
        else
        System.out.println("Incorrect Password!");
    }
    else
    {
        authenticated = false;
        System.out.println("Incorrect Username!");
    }



    return authenticated;
}
```

Comment: what you want to do ? your query will return last record from matched result.

Comment: Well I'm trying to authenticate a user, so it has too look through the whole table to see if it matches any combination. I haven't tested it as I don't have access to the MySQL DB. I just sat and coded that but I'm not sure if it'll work.

Comment: Such examples are available on net and what your asking is the logic which is irrelevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean authUser(String user, String pass) throws Exception
{
    boolean authenticated = false;
    int id = 0;
    String username = "", password = "";

    Connection authConn = getConnection();

    Statement stat = authConn.createStatement();
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM users where userName='" + user + "';");
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);

    while(rs.next()){
        id = rs.getInt("id");
        username = rs.getString("user");
        password = rs.getString("pass");
    }

    authConn.close();

    if(username.equals(user)){
        if(password.equals(pass)){
           authenticated = true;
        }else{
           authenticated = false;
           System.out.println("Incorrect Password!");
        }
    }
    else{
        authenticated = false;
        System.out.println("Incorrect Username!");
    }
    return authenticated;
}
```

use while instead of `if` to get data. You know that there one record though also.

You also have not made `authenticated = false` while password doesn't match.

You have to provide query that which user details you are searching for.
Because suppose there are 1 lac user then it ll list all user & gives you last row instead search user as per he/she has added userName, that ll be better.

& make sure that userName or userId will be unique otherwise it ll return multiple rows.

& it ll be more better if you ll use `PreparedStatement`.

**You have to provide `username` or `userid` in `where` clause to make process of authentication more efficient.**

Comment: why do you need to order by ? you are searching for a specific user

Comment: @vlatkozelka : oh sorry for that, I have also removed limit clause.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad example, especially when dealing with user input:

```
Statement stat = authConn.createStatement();
String query = ("SELECT * FROM users where userName='" + user + "' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);
```

Replace above with:

```
// got rid of ORDER BY and LIMIT - shouldn't userName be unique?
// in your select list avoid '*' select only columns that you need
PreparedStatement ps = authConn.prepareStatement("SELECT pass FROM users where userName = ?");
ps.setString(1, user);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    password = rs.getString("pass");
}
authConn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put WHERE clause into your SQL query to match USER and PASSWORD in table. If it found any row in table then you can authenticate USER else user Access Denied.

```
public boolean authUser(String user, String pass) throws Exception
{
boolean authenticated = false;
int id = 0;
String username = "", password = "";

Connection authConn = getConnection();

Statement stat = authConn.createStatement();
String query = ("SELECT * FROM users Where user = '"+username+"' and pass = '"+password+"');
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);

if(rs.next())
{
    System.out.println("Incorrect Password!");
    id = rs.getInt("id");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Incorrect Username!");
    authenticated = true;
}

authConn.close();


return authenticated;
```

}